# Form Runner Send button without following navigation to another page

Tags: orbeon

Is it possible to configure Send button, so that xml is being sent without following navigation to the send.success.uri but showing the result dialog as from persistence?

Comment: Answered below on navigation. Not sure what you want with the navigation dialog though?

Comment: With orbeon 3.9 we have implemented some logic using ajax in the result dialog. So after the form data is saved we can initiate different kind of data processing in the persistence layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with Orbeon Forms 4.3, which has a more flexible system to configure buttons and actions. See [Form Runner: Buttons and Processes](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner%3a-Buttons-and-Processes) for the documentation.

In particular, the `send` action by default doesn't cause navigation by default.